# Connecting to Internet with 3G modem

Tags: installation

Im using a 3G modem to try to connect to internet. How to setup my connection in ubuntu 12.04, I have a vodafone 3G Modem?

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Press on the network icon that's on the top. Select the last option in the menu called "Edit Connections..."(Or search in Unity for "Network" and open "Network Connections" from the results). Now select "Mobile Broadband". Press "Add" and from there I hope you can handle the rest.